# Additional custom page building hook for BuddyPress profile page

Tags: buddypress

I want to create an additional page like in the picture below and I want to show the codes I want in the page, I researched but I couldn't get a result. What is the hook name I can do this?

https://prnt.sc/wccy4e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/shanebp/5d3d2f298727a0a036e5) shows how to add a simple nav tab + subnav.

If you want to load specific templates ( perhaps from a plugin ) into a custom nav screen, you need to use [bp_register_template_stack](https://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/upgrading-older-plugins-that-bundle-custom-templates-for-bp-1-7/#3-get-acquainted-with-the-bp-template-stack), and the code becomes more complicated.

This is [an example](https://codex.buddypress.org/add-custom-tab-to-groups-directory/) for adding a custom tab to groups and loading templates via `bp_register_template_stack`.